# PGFPlots: How to selectively clip specific marks by axes?

Tags: pgfplots

In this MWE, I need to clip the yellow squares marks by the axes while keeping the red diamond ones intact.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0, xmax=1,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            domain=0:1,
            every axis plot post/.append style={
                line width=2pt,
            }
        ]
            \addplot [ mark=square*, mark size=4pt,
            mark options={fill=yellow, line width = 0.5pt}, samples = 3 ] {x};
            \addplot [ only marks,  mark=diamond*, mark size=5pt,
            mark options={fill=red, line width = 0.5pt}, samples = 2 ] {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Addendum

`clip marker paths` option doesn't work when using layers. How can it be solved in this case?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
layers/my layer set/.define layer set={bg,main,fg}{},
set layers=my layer set,
mark layer=like plot}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0, xmax=1,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            domain=0:1,
            every axis plot post/.append style={
                line width=2pt,
            }
        ]
            \addplot [ mark=square*, mark size=4pt,
            mark options={fill=yellow, line width = 0.5pt}, samples = 3, clip marker paths, on layer = bg ] {x};
            \addplot [ only marks,  mark=diamond*, mark size=5pt,
            mark options={fill=red, line width = 0.5pt}, samples = 2, on layer = fg ] {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the option `clip marker paths` to the plot doing the yellow markers.

**Edit:** As pointed out, this does not work when using layers. However, using `clip mode=individual` instead seems to work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
layers/my layer set/.define layer set={bg,main,fg}{},
set layers=my layer set,
mark layer=like plot}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0, xmax=1,
            ymin=0, ymax=1,
            domain=0:1,
            every axis plot post/.append style={
                line width=2pt,
            }
        ]
            \addplot [ mark=square*, mark size=4pt,
            mark options={fill=yellow, line width = 0.5pt}, samples = 3, on layer = bg,
            clip mode=individual % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            ] {x};
            \addplot [ only marks,  mark=diamond*, mark size=5pt,
            mark options={fill=red, line width = 0.5pt}, samples = 2, on layer = fg ] {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, this option fails when I draw plots on layers. What might be the reason?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I've edited the solution; I think it now also works with layers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I came across a weird behavior in my real problem, not this MWE. When I set `clip mode = individual` for a specific plot, marks weren't clipped. However, when setting `clip mode = individual` globally inside `axis` options and `clip = false` for other plots than the one I need to clip its marks, it works and gives me the desired result. Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I'm sure there is an explanation, but I don't know your specific code (which is apparently different from the code in your question). See the pgfplots manual for a discussion of the clipping options; in my version it is section 4.20.2.